# How to extract the SharePoint List data into SQL Server using SQL Query(without using SSIS)?

Tags: sql-server, database, sharepoint-list

I just want to extract the SharePoint List data into SQL Server using SQL Query(without using SSIS)?

Thanks,
Lawrance A

Answer (score 1):

There is no such direct way I can recall of.

SSIS is actually a good approach, but if you insist, the easiest in my view would be to use the REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest